# Get data fro firestore with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get data from Firestore but i can't, i need to know if my code is ok, because it doesn't work or something else is missing.

This is my firestore services

fireservices.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import { firebaseConfig } from '../firebase_const';
    import 'firebase/firestore';

        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

class FireServices{

    static async getLocalization(idOfert) {
        firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(idOfert)
    }

}

export default FireServices;
```

And this is my class, this class use the method to get data

SecondClass.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FireServices from '../services/fireservices';



export default class SecondClass extends React.Component {

componentDidMount = async () => {

        this.onStart()
}


onStart = () => {
            FireServices.getLocalization('email@hotmail.com').get().then(doc => {
            console.log(doc)
        })
    }

render(){
 return (
  <View>
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: Something more specific that "it doesn't work" would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning from getLocalization.

It should be

```
static async getLocalization(idOfert) {
    return firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(idOfert)
}
```

Comment: _fireservices.default.getLocalization('email@hotmail.com').get is not a function